# JSOM - Update Star Ratings on Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

I've been attempting to update the rating values (shown as star ratings) for items that I am fetching from a list via REST and displaying in a Content Editor Webpart.

I am essentially rebuilding the star rating functionality.

I am successfully pulling and displaying the average star rating, however I now need to update star rating from my custom page via JavaScript/JSOM

The function that I am planning to attach to each star is as follows:

```
function SetRating(ratingObj) {
//http://sharepointpals.com/post/SetRating-in-Reputation-Class-in-SharePoint-2013-using-Javascript-and-C-CSOM
$.ajax({
    url:ratingObj.globalUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + ratingObj.listName + "')?select=Id",
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose","accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" 
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var clientContext;
        var website;
        console.log(data);
        var listID = data.d.Id;
        //var spCtx = clientContext;
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
            var spCtx = new SP.ClientContext(website);
            console.log(spCtx);
            Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setRating(spCtx, listID, ratingObj.itemID, ratingObj.ratingValue);
            spCtx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.RatingSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.RatingFailure));
            function RatingSuccess(sender, args) {
                alert('Rating Done Successfully');
            }

            function RatingFailure(sender, args) {
                alert('SetRating failed:' + args.get_message());//note that you will get error if try like twice
            }
    },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

}

I am passing all parameters in as an object. My problem is that the line:  `Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setRating(spCtx, listID, ratingObj.itemID, ratingObj.ratingValue);`

Does not seem to run, however I am not too sure why. I am pretty new to CSOM/JSOM so I am not too sure what else to try.

Further info

The list I am querying is on the parent site to the site this code is running on.

I am not receiving the alerts in the code at all so the function seems to be completely failing on the above line. I am also not getting any errors logged in the developer tools console.

I am referencing the required files to my knowledge:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name='sp.js' runat='server' ondemand='false' localizable='false' loadafterui='true' />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name='sp.runtime.js' runat='server' ondemand='false' localizable='false' loadafterui='true' />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name='sp.core.js' runat='server' ondemand='false' localizable='false' loadafterui='true' />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name='reputation.js' runat='server' ondemand='false' localizable='false' loadafterui='true' />
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if any further info/clarification is required

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I have updated the SetRating function above, and everything is working except that I now receive Microsoft.Office is undefined. This happens after page load as I am executing the above function on a click event that I am attaching to the star rating "a" tags on the page.

Comment: A quick check shows me ``reputation.js`` is not the file you need .. see answer below

Answer (score 0):

`EnsureScriptFunc()` shouldn't be necessary if this is a user interaction...thus all async scripts will most likely have loaded by the time a user clicks .. no need to check if reputation.js has loaded

If you need the check either replace it with a plain vanilla JavaScript check to check for the Globals reputation.js adds

Or make sure to load scripts the SP.SOD (Script On Demand) SharePoint way:

https://www.eliostruyf.com/correctly-including-scripts-display-templates/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410742(v=office.14).aspx

## Update: Microsoft.Office.Server.Reputation

If you display a View with List set to do star-ratings,
then do a CTRL-SHFT-F search in the Console

This namespace comes from a different JS file:
(*maybe it was `reputation.js` in SP2013 as all the blogs state*)

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have removed the EnsureScriptFunc() from the function and made some updates. I am now receiving a new error, see update message above.